# Searching in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've an array:

```
    Array
(
    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1434971582:11
        )

    [_edit_last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
        )

    [_wp_page_template] => Array
        (
            [0] => page-templates/langenfeldDreiSpalterMitSiderbarsRL.php
        )

    [_wpas_done_all] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [hefo_before] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [hefo_after] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [sharing_disabled] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [spacious_page_layout] => Array
        (
            [0] => left_sidebar
        )

    [_thumbnail_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2641
        )

    [ort] => Array
        (
            [0] => langenfeld
        )

)
```

I want to save the "ort" in a variable.

```
[ort] => Array
    (
        [0] => langenfeld
    )
```

My code give me the values of the array but how can I save the values?
My code:

```
foreach ($gpc as $k){
    foreach ($k as $v){
        //echo $v;
    }
}
```

I thought something like that:

```
$ort = $v['ort'];
```

But that's not working for me. Can someone help?

Comment: $var = $gpc['ort'][0]; ....... monday..... sry.

Comment: How it's `But that's not working for me.`? Also you can edit question instead of making error fix descriptions in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working properly

```
 $arr =    Array
    (
        '_edit_lock' => Array
            (
                '0' => "1434971582:11",
            ),

        '_edit_last' => Array
            (
                '0' => "11",
            ),

        '_wp_page_template' => Array
            (
                '0' => "page-templates/langenfeldDreiSpalterMitSiderbarsRL.php",
            ),

        '_wpas_done_all' => Array
            (
                '0' => "1",
            ),

        'hefo_before' => Array
            (
                '0' => "0",
            ),

        'hefo_after' => Array
            (
                '0' => "0",
            ),

        'sharing_disabled' => Array
            (
                '0' => "1",
            ),

        'spacious_page_layout' => Array
            (
                '0' => "left_sidebar",
            ),

        '_thumbnail_id' => Array
            (
                '0' => "2641",
            ),

        'ort' => Array
            (
                '0' => "langenfeld",
            ),

    );

    $ort = $arr["ort"];
    print_r($ort);
```

// output

```
   Array
  (
      [0] => langenfeld
   )
```

if you directly want langenfeld

```
   $ort = $arr['ort'][0];
```

//this will output - `langenfeld`